# Dimensioning Confusion

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Can someone help me with the dimensioning convention used here?Usually the coordinates are given as cartesion X,Y,but I am unable to understand this convention.
Also each individual hole size is not mentioned,so how does one find the hole size if they are close in diameter.Here the sizes are quite disparate,so it is visually obvious.

Cheers & TIA[image]

Answer (score 2):

Top left is given as zero origin and all centres are measured from that point horizontal and vertical.

Two holes have diameter details with one saying 6 off and the smaller 25.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I figured it out. 10 4x means there are 4 holes at 10mm X axis.Similarly for Y axis.Hence you can get the coordinate of each hole individually.